# How to insert batch file into sql using Jboss Fuse Data Transformation

Tags: jboss, jbossfuse

I want to process a batch file into some Sql table and I'm thinking of using Data Transformation for it has the mapping funcionality which is very good. Is there any way to define a Target Type that can be helpful for this task?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If we go with Camel (which has several database-capable components) we will get a graphical depiction of the application flow through basic Fuse Tooling.  (There is no graphical mapper, though.)

[image: Fuse Tooling]

I hope that helps.  Camel really does make it easy to handle your messages and put them in a database-- but you can't drag-n-drop that part of the application design.

Rick

Comment: Thanks, Rick, after a long research I finally found a working example of data insertion from a flat file from Christina Lin:

https://vimeo.com/121135136
And yes, you're right, it's very easy with Camel to design the flow of this process but again the programming syntax makes it difficult for beginners  like me. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You can use the mapper if you want, but you might also give consideration to using Camel for this task.
Camel offers JPA, Hibernate, JDBC, SQL etc. all good ways to send data to a database.  Camel's got great flat-file handling skills, too, so it's a pretty easy task to set things up for the persistence part.

Comment: Yes, but I'd like to use a graphical tool like Teiid so I can easily map the fields from my sources to my destinations. Is there a chance to do so with Red Hat Jboss Fuse? Thanks

Comment: Hi Fran,
Yes, there is tooling available.   Please check out the Fuse 6.2 Tooling User Guide, available on the Red Hat portal.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, Rick. Do you remember the name of this graphical tool? I couldn't find it in the documentation page. Thanks again!

Comment: (Please see response below in new 'Answer'.  I couldn't figure out how to paste the image in this 'Reply'.)
Rick